# Attempting to start Thunderbird and getting Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird

My electric went out last night causing computer to crash and after I cannot start Thunderbird.

From the Launcher the timer spins and just stops. If I try entering thunderbird from terminal I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Is there a way to get Thunderbird working again?

Ubuntu 18.04
Thunderbird 1:60.9.0+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: If I lose power; I don't try and reboot my system normally when power returns, but boot a 'live' (eg. Ubuntu install media) and `fsck` (file system check) my partitions. Have you `fsck`'d your system?

Comment: @guiverc - no I haven't fsck 'd my partitions. I guess I've been lucky that other times I've not had any issues. I'll have to find/create a live disk and give it a try. Other apps seem happy. thx

Comment: Back up your system, then verify the archive created matches the source files. Back up your system a second time to different external media, then verify the second archive created matches the source files. Uninstall Thunderbird, reinstall Thunderbird, restore the Thunderbird data files.

Comment: @guiverc - fsck didn't help with this issue, but glad to add to my lose power process. thanks.

Comment: @K7AAY - uninstalling and reinstalling worked. If you want to add as an answer, then this can be marked as resolved (or should I answer my own question?). FYI - I agree backups are mandatory (did both). Didn't need to do any restore, just had to reinstall the Lightning add on. All mail and calendar entries appear. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Back up your system, then verify the archive created matches the source files.

Back up your system a second time to different external media, then verify the second archive created matches the source files.

Uninstall Thunderbird, reinstall Thunderbird, restore the Thunderbird data files.